# jQuery UI draggable - remove clone if a valid drop occurred

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to get something like the following to work but can't find the correct way to use the stop event for this.

I've got two columns where you can drag from the right to the left. I've got the revert function working correctly if the drop was invalid but I want to remove the item in the right column if a valid drop occurred on the left column. I know the conditional isn't correct but I'm not sure what flag to look for to determine if the drop was valid.

```
$("#sortable2 li").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable1",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (drop == "valid") 
            { 
               $(this).remove(); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can handle removing the original element using the `receive` event on the `.sortable`

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/nJPkU/)

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) { // add this handler
        ui.item.remove(); // remove original item
    }
});

$("#sortable2 li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable1",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: I modified the above example so that element from 1st list can be moved to second and from 2nd to 1st. But once the element has been moved to another list, it can't move back to it's original list.

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can compare the differences between [event-start](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start) and [event-stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop).  Use a debugger to break into the Event Function and you can see the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sorting anything and want the original item to be remove as the drop is valid, you can just remove the `helper:"clone"`.

> ```
> $("#sortable2 li").draggable({
>     revert: "invalid",
> });
> ```

Comment: using the default `helper: "original"` has limitations. e.g. you can't use the `appendTo` options.